# React-native CLI has stopped building ios projects entirely

Tags: react-native

I was working on a project when I tried running

```
react-native run-ios
```

and I got stuck at:

```
Building using "xcodebuild -project myProj.xcodeproj -configuration Debug 
-scheme myProj -destination id=489799D4-EB4F-42B0-9716-73B5A376A82F 
-derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:

IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/me/Documents/Projekt/myProj/ios/build
```

The error persists even when creating a new project with

```
react-native init
```

I have tried reinstalling Xcode and deleting my ios folder and then upgrading react-native cli. When trying to open the project from Xcode, Xcode freezes and I have to force quit it.

Comment: Have you tried building it from Xcode rather than from the command line?

Comment: Oh yes, Xcode freezes as well when I try to open it from there, and I have to force quit it. I can add that to the original post.

Comment: I can build via the expo app but I'd rather not..